# Trying to reorganize a random string so that all the letters are grouped up in the order that a different random string dictates

Tags: python

I am creating a matrix that will list these a random string of letters that are used for colors and they are to be organized so that, for example all of the G's will be together and then R, etc.

```
legoString = "YRRBRBYBGRBRGRRRYRGBRBGBBRBG"
shuffledColString = "YRBG"

for letter in shuffledColString:
    for index in range(len(legoString)):

        if letter == legoString[index]:
                legoString = legoString.replace(legoString[index], "") + "R"

        elif letter == legoString[index]:
                legoString = legoString.replace(legoString[index], "") + "G"

        elif letter == legoString[index]:
                legoString = legoString.replace(legoString[index], "") + "B"

        elif letter == legoString[index]:
                legoString = legoString.replace(legoString[index], "") + "C"

        elif letter == legoString[index]:
                legoString = legoString.replace(legoString[index], "") + "Y"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
legoString = "YRRBRBYBGRBRGRRRYRGBRBGBBRBG"
shuffledColString = "YRBG"

ns="".join(sorted(legoString,key=lambda x:shuffledColString.index(x)))
print(ns)

#OR IF ABOVE IS NOT CLEAR
ns=""
for c in shuffledColString:
    ns=ns+ c*legoString.count(c)

print(ns)
```